# Android UI is not updating before a method starting

Tags: java, android, user-interface

I'm making a Tic-Tac-Toe game on Android. My game is running well, but I have a problem with it. When user touch on a tile, I update the UI and then call `ComputerPlay()` method. But the UI only update after `ComputerPlay()` method is completed. I don't know how, sorry, my English is bad and I don't know how to search the answer.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
             if (currentTurn == Constants.HUMAN && board.isEmptyCell(r, c)) {                                     
                  //update the UI
                  v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cell_touched);
             }
             return true;
         case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
             if (currentTurn == Constants.HUMAN && board.isEmptyCell(r, c)) {                                   
                 //update the tile where user touched
                 v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cell_normal);
                 board.makeMove(r, c, currentTurn, options.getHumanPiece());

                 if (board.checkWinner(currentTurn)) {//if user wins
                     win++;
                     tvWin.setText(String.format("Win: %d", win));
                     tvNotice.setText(R.string.winNotice);
                 } else if (board.isFull()) { //if draw
                     draw++;
                     tvDraw.setText(String.format("Draw: %d", draw));
                     tvNotice.setText(R.string.drawNotice);
                 } else {
                     // computer's turn
                     currentTurn = Constants.COMPUTER;
                     ComputerPlay();
                 }
             }
             return true;
     }
     return false;
}
```

In the code below, when user touches on a tile, I update the UI first and then check for game status. If the game is not end, I call method `ComputerPlay()`. But the problem is: The UI is really updated after `ComputerPlay()` method is completed (take more time to search the best move for Computer). I want the UI is updated before `ComputerPlay()` method starts. How can I do this?

Comment: simply call `v.invalidate()` after you made your changes to the view

Comment: @Nicolas Simon: Do you mean: I just call `v.invalidate()` after 'v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cell_normal);`?

Comment: or after board.MakeMove() in case you're doing more computation on the view in this function

Answer (score 1):

If ComputerPlay() is a long-running method, and you want your UI to update before it is done, you should run ComputerPlay() in an other thread.

Comment: can you elaborate a bit more?